# Console log data got from graphql api

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, graphql, nuxt.js

I have the following method from my vuex action block where I send user email and password  to backend server and get userId and token on success.

```js
  async signIn ({ commit }, formData) {
    const graphqlQuery = {
      query: `
        query{
            loginData(
              email: "${formData.email}",
              password: "${formData.password}"
            ) {userId, token}
        }
      `
    }
    const res = await this.$axios.post('http://localhost:8080/graphql', graphqlQuery, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    console.log(res.data) //works
    console.log(res.data.loginData.token) //doesn't work
    commit('loadUserData', true, res.data.loginData.token, res.data.loginData.userId)
    return res.status
  }
```

I can confirm that I'm getting the response data with `console.log(res.data)`. The response data I get is:

[image]

But when I `console.log(res.data.loginData)` I get undefined. And blank on `console.log(res.data.loginData.token)` and `console.log(res.data.loginData.token)`.

How do I extract the required data `token` and `userId` ?

I'm using webstorm as my IDE and it shows `loginData` as method refering to my backend graphql resolver method.

[image]

My frontend is made on Nuxt js, backend on node js with graphql.
Does anyone have any idea to overcome this issue ?

Comment: console.log(res.data.data.loginData)

Comment: Thanks, never realized that there was double layer of data.